# Convergent sequences theorem notation explanation (in $\mathbb{R}^k$)

Tags: real-analysis, analysis, convergence-divergence

So here is a theorem from "Pricniples of Mathematical Analysis" by Rudin, Theorem 3.4: (I do not understand the theorem, but a good starting point would be an explanation of this particular notation they use)

" Suppose $\vec{x_n} \in \mathbb{R}^k \ (n=1,2,3,...)$ and 
$$\vec{x_n} = (\alpha_{1,n},...,\alpha_{k,n}).$$
Then $\{ \vec{x_n}\}$ converges to $\vec{x} = (\alpha_1,...,\alpha_k)$ iff $$\lim_{n \rightarrow \infty} \alpha_{j,n}=\alpha_j \ \ \ \ (1\leq j \leq k).$$"

I do not follow what they mean by $\vec{x_n}$, it appears that how they define it, it is a row vector of some matrix. So perhaps the rows of that matrix can be considered as a sequence in $\mathbb{R}^k$? But then what is $\vec{x}$? What is this saying anyway? And then perhaps you could give an example in $\mathbb{R}^3$?

Comment: he is just saying that a sequence of points in $\mathbb{R}^k$ converges if and only if the induced sequences on each co-ordinate converge

Answer (score 2, accepted):

$\vec{x_n}$ is a sequence of $k$-tuples (points in $k$- dimensional space) in $\mathbb{R}^k=\mathbb{R} \times \mathbb{R} \times \cdots \mathbb{R}$ ($k$ times). $\vec{x}$ is the limit of the sequence. Since $\mathbb{R}^k$ is a vector space, the vector notation is used for its elements, such as a sequence of vectors and the limit of the sequence.

The main point of this theorem is stating that $\vec{x_n}$ converges to $\vec{x}$ if each component of the $k$-tuple converges to the corresponding component of the $k$-tuple of the limit.

A simple example for $\mathbb{R}^3$ would be the sequence $\vec{x_n}=(
\frac{1}{n}, \frac{1}{n}, \frac{1}{n})$ this converges to the limit $\vec{x}=(0, 0, 0)$ as $n\to \infty$.

Comment: it is not necessary to have the same sequences in each of the entries in the vector, correct? We can have any sequence and as long as each sequence converges, we can say that $\vec{x_n}$ converges to some $\vec{x}$? Also, I assume then that $\alpha_{1,n}$ simply denotes the n-th element of the 1st sequence and thus $\alpha_{k,n}$ denotes the n-th element of the k-th sequence?

Comment: Yes the sequences do not need to be the same, I just used that example for simplicity. And your understanding of the notation is correct.